# Смена картинки при наведении на текст

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 4 текста. При наведении на каждый из них выходит определенная картинка. Вопрос в том, что мне нужно слайдер из них. То есть, изначально есть какая-то картинка, при наведении на например на `Текст1` выезжает другая картинка соответствующая теме `текста1`и через секунду вторая тоже по этой теме и картинка, которая уже уехала исчезает. И так со всеми текстами. У меня в коде они просто появляются при наведении на текст и то только одна картинка. Как можно реализовать чтобы хотя бы 2 картинки появлялось с разрывом в 1 секунду в слайдере при наведении?

Вот html:

```
<p1 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center xs-mb50 xs-font wow fadeIn">
            <p>Text1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</p1>
<p2 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center wow fadeIn">
            <p>Text2</p><br><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</p2>
<div class="pic" style="border-radius: 20px;"></div>
<p3 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center xs-mb50 xs-font wow fadeIn">
            <p>Text3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</p3>
<p4 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center wow fadeIn">
            <p>Text4</p>
        </div>
    </div>   
</p4>
```

Вот css:

```
.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/1.png);
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}

p1:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/8.png);
}

p2:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/9.png);
} 

p3:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/11.png);
}    

p4:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/5.png);
}
```

Comment: Посмотри вот такой пример, может поможет - https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/gmbVer

Comment: @Lukas не помогло